# React event handler not triggering

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react, so sorry if this is basic.

I have this code, which does NOT trigger the onClick function:

```
var ContactItem = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            React.createElement('form', {className: 'ContactItem'}, [
                React.createElement('input', {type:'text', placeholder: this.props.placeholder}),
                React.createElement('button', { onClick: this.onClick }, this.props.action)
            ]
        ))
    },

    onClick: function() { alert('hi') }       
});

var ContactForm = React.createClass({
    render : function(){
        return(
            React.createElement('form', {className: 'ContactForm'}, [
                React.createElement(ContactItem, {placeholder: '<name>', action: 'send it!', onclick: this.onclick }, null)
            ])
        );
    }
});

var element = React.createElement(ContactForm, { action: 'send!'})
ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('react-app'))
```

But, if I change this only following line, it does trigger (that is, I directly instantiate ContactItem instead of ContactForm):

```
    var element = React.createElement(ContactItem, { action: 'send!'})
```

Any idea why this is so? Thanks!

Comment: Did you consider using JSX?

Comment: Not yet, just because I'm just starting with React and found it easier to understand it through plain js, but will do :-)

Comment: This is highly unreadable, I would suggest you to move on JSX asap :)

Comment: @Ariel, trust me - learning JSX will make it easier. All you need to know is how elements are created and what parameters the function takes (type, props, children)

Comment: Thanks @Chris, I know! But just got curious about why this doesn't work. Sure at some point gonna tackle JSX and all the packages that make React life easier!

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/5qypcggo/

Comment: Thanks @Chris! Really strange why it repros on browser but not in jsfiddle...

Comment: I'm going to vote to close this because it seems like minor error that's unlikely to be any useful/helpful for future readers. Though, do yourself a favor and use JSX nonetheless ;). Good luck.

Comment: I understand JSX is needed for production React. But I'm just experimenting with plain React API's, that's why asking this. It's like someone coming up with an error in his/her javascript and telling them to use typescript :-)

Comment: @Ariel, that's not an accurate comparison at all. And JSX has nothing to do with production/development environments. Either way, using React without JSX is perfectly valid, I'm just encouraging JSX because it will save you headaches. I've been working with React for 2 years now and I can tell you that nobody uses React *without* JSX, no matter project, environment, etc. Literally 99,99% of all React apps. :) If you want to experiment around, that's perfectly fine - just giving you a heads-up, that's all. :)

Comment: Thanks @Chris, appreciate your comments, and makes me clear the way to go with this.